# Cannot checkout from svn: svn: E000002

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, directory, windows-10, svn-checkout

I am using IntelliJ on Windows and svn is installed (cygwin). But checkout doesnt work either:

> Cannot checkout from svn: svn: E000002: Can't make directory '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.2/C:\Users\username\Desktop': No such file or directory

Making the directory seems to be strange. What do you think? How to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem. When given the option of which svn format to use, select `1.7 format`

[image]

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at the path that gives you the error:

> /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community
>   Edition 2016.1.2/C:\Users\username\Desktop

Does it look valid? Not at all.

I'm not sure about the root cause, but most likely IntelliJ IDEA on Windows won't work with SVN that's working via cygwin. Use SVN built for Windows. You can grab one of the packages specified at https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows (at the very bottom of the page).

Comment: That was indeed the problem. IntelliJ was picking up the svn client from PATH which was Cygwin installation. Installing Tortoise SVN with CLI tools and explicitly specifying the client in IDE configuration resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using cygwin svn which wants POSIX paths (using forward slashes) but you are giving it Windows paths (using back slashes and has drive letters). It sometimes works when you give it relative paths but will never work with absolute paths as a windows path starts with a drive letter and a POSIX absolute path starts with a forward slash.

If you want to use the cygwin svn, then you need to convert your windows path to the cygwin path. cygwin has a tool available called "cygpath". They way you would do your checkout would be:

```
svn co `cygpath "C:\Users\username\Desktop"`
```

notice the backticks (the same key as the ~ on the keyboard) before the command cygpath and after the end quote to your path; that make the cygpath command run before passing the result as an argument to svn co. If your path has spaces, you will need an additional set of quotes outside of the backticks.